# Python list index bizarre behavior

Tags: python, list, jython

I have a section of code that somehow fails on the following `list.index` function:

```
for line in flines:
    for match in bad_data_regex.findall(line):
        assert line in flines
        index = flines.index(line)
        flines.pop(index)
        # other code that does not modify flines ....
```

My code fails on:

```
ScriptEngine.execute:Error in script Traceback (innermost last):
  File "<string>", line 168, in ?
ValueError: list.index(x): x not in list
```

If the value truly wasn't in the list, I should've gotten an `AssertionError` before the `list.index` function.

I'm using Jython 2.2.1 under Java version 1.6.0_18.

How is this possible?

EDIT:

Turns out the code that was generating that error was not what I have posted above. My Jython interpreter gave me the wrong line number, and happened to land on the line with the index function above.

The above code does work as I intended, although I realize it's not the best practice to modify a list while iterating over it. I'll try to avoid that whenever possible in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This probably happens because of the `flines.pop(index)` part. It is always a bad idea to change the list while you iterate over it.

Consider this example:

```
In [1]: a = range(5)

In [2]: for i in a:
   ...:     print a.pop()
   ...: 
4
3
2

In [3]: a
Out[3]: [0, 1]
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It turns out the code above does work as intended, but I'll refrain from modifying the same list I'm iterating over in the future.